Why is CORDIC an approach that can work with every sample and thus be more optimized for lower SNR condition
I want to know Why CORDIC is an approach that can work with every sample and thus be more optimized for lower SNR condition.
frequency divider

Please edit your questions with enough details so that we know what you're confused about.  CORDIC is, in one sense, just a way to implement trig functions -- which can be done by many other methods.  Perhaps you could quote the part of the question or answer that mentions CORDIC, and then say what you don't get about it.

yes, please be more detailed about what you don't understand about Dan's answer – in the end he's just describing "use a phase difference detector (e.g. implemented via CORDIC), and divide the detected phases by two, before accumulating them". Is your question A) about why dividing phase increments by 2 halves frequency, or B) about how that behaves statistically in low-SNR situations or C) about how you can implement a phase difference detector in CORDIC? (you probably have multiple questions! that's OK! But please start with one very specific one! That's easier to answer, and answers…

… might be easier to understand!)

Acutually, I am exploring if the CORDIC algorithm (maybe phase detection method) can work well in low SNR conditions compared with frequency divider (applied in the phase-locked loop).
More details are comparsion between two phase detection method .
So, I am interested in the Dan's answer.

Maybe, I want to know how that behaves statistically in low-SNR situations.

OK, now you're making up a completely new direction! Can you Edit your question to say you want to compare with a phase-locked loop. Describe what you understand from Dan's answer, and ask a clear single question: As I said above, as currently stated, your question is a little bit on the too broad side. Can you try to narrow it down a bit for us? You can later ask new questions if our answers don't answer all your questions, but we need something to start.

In case you haven't picked up on it yet: this is Stackexchange.  Unlike other forums, which prefer you leave the question unchanged and put important information in the comments, Stackexchange wants a clear question that could be answered by one answer.  Then we follow by supplying our best version of that one answer.  You're expected to do your part by editing your question for clarity.  When someone feels it can be answered, it will be answered.

You may want to change the title, too -- CORDIC is just a fast way to solve certain transcendental functions, like $\sin$, $\cos$, $\sqrt \cdot$, etc.  There's no reason you have to use CORDIC to do so -- it's just the fastest way to do it on some processors.

OK.
Dan's answer is "The approach described by @JRE is identical to how a digital frequency divider works and has the limitation that it is only edge sensitive (so works well in high SNR conditions but not optimum for lower SNR's where we may have multiple zero crossings as the horizontal axis is transitioned). Here is an approach(CORDIC) that can work with every sample and thus be more optimized for lower SNR conditions........"
The last words:".....for lower SNR conditions.....",I don't understand why it is optimized for lower SNR conditions. Please explain this sentence. Please.
